# Lost Lydia (Skyrim)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have lost Lydia, I lost her when starting the companions quest The Silver Hand because she was dismissed, after the quest I looked for her at my house in Falkreath (I have the Hearthfire DLC) and could not find her, I looked in Dragonsreach with the same results, I had a wedding at the temple of mara and she appeared at the wedding but left and I could not get to her. I also checked at Jorrvaskr to see if she stayed there but I did not find her, I even looked in the hall of the dead to see if she died but no luck. Is this a bug, I play on the Xbox 360 by the way. Let me clarify that the last time I saw her was at the wedding.

Comment: I found her in Markarth prison once. No idea how she got there though. Ended up just laughing it off.

Comment: Do you have a save where she was still with you? Without console access that might be the easiest bet to get her back.

Comment: With the way skyrim saves I lost it, it autosaved too many times. :(

Comment: I was able to go back far enough that I could get to the wedding, I will have to redo some stuff but I caught her on the way out before she went to where ever she was. She had the steward dialog from the DLC but I never saw her at my house, i'm just going to assume she took a vacation!

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That might be related to the [follower Forsworn Conspiracy quest bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108315/4797) or the [game mechanic where followers can get arrested.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/286565/4797). This question might also be related to the latter.

Comment: @galacticninja Sure it's possible, but at the time I hadn't ever even _been_ to Markarth. It was quite a surprise to find her there sharing a cell with Barbas.

Comment: Funny, none of the answers in the suggested duplicates will work. OP can't use the console, fast travel/entering a new area doesn't help, and the follower was not at Breezehome (place of origin).

Comment: The problem is that I looked at every home I have, inside and out, I looked in Dragonsreach and she was not there either, I have never asked her to wait anywhere in the game yet besides Whiterun and I never saw her there, I lost her after she was dismissed for the companion's quest The Silver Hand and I did not kill her because she showed up at the wedding later, but I have never seen her otherwise and the dialog list when I got her at the wedding suggested that she was dismissed, I hope this clarifies everything.

Comment: You said you checked your Falkreath home and Dragonsreach. Did you check Breezehome? As your housecarl for Whiterun Hold, she will always return there if not bound to another location, so long as you own the house.

Comment: I never bought Breezehome. So unless it was a glitch she didn't return there.

Comment: I'd check the jails next time. See: [Lydia goes to jail](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/286565/4797)

Comment: Maybe it's associated with when I first became a Werewolf and she got arrested or something?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reload a save from the wedding to get her back, I will have to redo some quests but at least she's back.